# Make directories incrementally, move file into directory - loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a script that will run through a list of files and for each file create an incremental directory and then move that file into the new directory. I'm stuck on getting the file to move.

```
n=1

for file in /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/untitled\ folder/*.zip; do   
    mkdir /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/untitled\ folder/test/$((n++))
    sleep 5s
    mv $file /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/untitled\ folder/test/"$((n++))" 
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're incrementing `$n` twice, so when you move the file, the directory doesn't exist. I think you want:

```
n=1

for file in /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/untitled\ folder/*.zip; do
    mkdir /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/untitled\ folder/test/$n
    sleep 5s
    mv $file /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/untitled\ folder/test/$n
    # Edited per Etan's comment, much less confusing this way
    $((n++))
done
```

Comment: Right idea wrong fix. `$((n++))` returns the old value of `n` and then increments it so this still has the directory wrong. Either use `$((++n))` in the first line, increment in the second line, or increment before or after both lines.

Comment: Still getting an error `usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory`

Comment: I like the incrementing at the end, because it's more obvious what you're trying to do.

Comment: Works now. Thanks fellas!

Comment: I'll give the check in 4 minutes when the site lets me